# Please tell me: Who TF am I?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Who TF am I?

If you can fathom out the clue, please tell me who I am, and who can join me!

---

Okay, here is a hint

> 1. Who TF am I  - is the clue
>  2. Cryptic crossworders should take note of the following:
>  "If you can fathom out the clue"

Some relevant knowledge

> I came from Canada, and now you can also find me in the UK, South Africa and New Zealand. Those of you from other countries can still solve but may need a bit of googling to get the full answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> **[The Women's Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_Institute)**, also known as the **WI**, for short.

Because:

> If you take the letters of WHOTFAMI and remove the letters of FATHOM (i.e. [take] 'fathom out' [of] the clue), you are left with the letters **W** and **I**.

This fits the background to the puzzle, because...

> The WI was founded in Stoney Creek, Ontario, **Canada**, by Erland and Janet Lee, as a community-based organisation for women. Further branches of it can these days be found in **the UK, South Africa and New Zealand**.

Who can join?

> The clue's in the name - women! (Over the age of 18...)

Comment: Hi Stiv - glad you got it! I'd be interested if you can think of a hint that isn't quite so direct as the one I gave. Maybe it just needed the magic word "cryptic" - perhaps as a tag?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I wonder whether you could have said something like rot13(V nz abg uneq, V nz abg byq, V nz abg npr, ... naq pyhr bar ol bar gur yrggref gung jrer gb or erzbirq - U, B, N, ... naq sbyybj vg hc jvgu gur cbfvgvir qrsvavgvba pyhr: "V nz sebz Pnanqn, ohg nyfb...") In fact that's quite a nice idea for a puzzle mechanic and I've just published it for all to see in a comment! D'oh - should have used it myself! :)

Comment: delete it quick! I 've got it!

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Haha, nah I'll leave it here :) Who knows, maybe I'll slip it in secretly somewhere one day... ;-)

Comment: When I post a puzzle I never use the same type twice if I can help. I just get an idea out of the blue and turn it into a one-off. Also I like to make everything as compact as possible so although your idea is a good one, it's too wordy for me!

Answer (score -1):

You are 'Commonwealth Games' previously known as 'British Empire Games'.The Game was founded by a canadian journalist called Melville Marks Robinson. The countries which were part of the british colonial empire took part in the games.
Today 54 countries are part of commonwealth games. The four countries mentioned above are the only countries that participated in every commonwealth games conducted every four years.

Comment: How does this connect to the clue?

Comment: I didn't no this is the only answer. 'I came from canada' indicated  the founder/birthplace. Since NZ,SA along with CAN were British colonies it was easy to correlate.

Comment: Sorry, this is incorrect. The clue is  "Who TF am I".  The instructions are "If you can fathom out the clue, please tell me who I am, and who can join me!"

Comment: P.S. You can hide your answers (so as not to spoil it for others) by using the characters 
">! " at the beginning of the line.  To make line breaks in that mode, put two spaces at the end of each line before pressing Return.